# System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Exceptions.ParseException: 'Type 'System.IO.DirectoryInfo' not found'

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-core, dynamic-linq

I'm trying to parse a dynamic expression and get the error **System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Exceptions.ParseException: 'Type 'System.IO.DirectoryInfo' not found'**

I'm using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core 1.2.12 in .NET 5 project.

The dynamic expression is

```
new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(x)
```

where x is the path string that will be passed.

Answer (score 2):

For this to work, you'll need:

1. Latest System.Linq.Dynamic.Core (v1.2.18)
2. Set `ParsingConfig`: `AllowNewToEvaluateAnyType` to `true`
3. Use `(~ as path)` instead of `(x)`

Example:

```cs
// Arrange
var config = new ParsingConfig { AllowNewToEvaluateAnyType = true };
var queryable = new[] { "test" }.AsQueryable();

// Act
var result = queryable.Select(config, "new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(~ as path)").ToDynamicArray().First();

// Assert
Assert.NotNull(result);
Assert.Equal(result.Name, "test");
```